# Find the area and perimeter of a self-intersecting polygon using out of order coordinate points.

Tags: geometry, area

I was wondering if there was any algorithm or approach to find the perimeter and more importantly the area of a self-intersecting polygon using an array coordinate points.
[image: Overlapping polygon]

The problem is that coordinates aren't in order and there can be multiple coordinates for one x or y value.

Reordering the coordinates from a programming standpoint, although may not be necessary, was very difficult and certain situations wouldn't be possible. For example, I wrote some code that wouldn't register a coordinate point if there were already two values for the same x or y value, unless it was out of their bounds which in that case it would replace the lowest or highest one depending on how close it is to each one. However, I realized that in some cases such as on edges it can be essential to have maybe three or more points on one x value such as illustrated below.
[image: Three points one x value]

I also noticed that my method isn't helpful because if the use went back and added another coordinate it would just recalculate it by adding the newest coordinate on the end which might cause the shape to overlap instead of rearranging the coordinates to draw out the new shape.

Comment: The area depends on the order in which the vertices are connected. So if you don't know the order, no algorithm can tell you the area.

Comment: If you know the order is there any way of finding the area given the coordinates?

Comment: I don't, but the comments under [accepted answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10049454/3717023) point out something exists.